# How to check directory size/how to assure that relocating files is complete

Tags: python, directory, operating-system, size, filesize

I have a script, that traverse trough watchfolder `rootdir` in which there are another folders. Each folder can contain: `movie.mp4, trailer.mp4, xmlfile.xml, picture.jpg, subtitles1.dfxp, subtitles2.dfxp`.

The script then begin to assess if files can be packed into archive - the requirement is finding: `movie.mp4, picture.jpg, xmlfile.xml`.
The rest of files are optional.

There is a case of problem I face:

1. Suppose that we have a folder `testfolder` that I want to move to `rootdir`.
2. The `testfolder` contains files: `movie.mp4, trailer.mp4, subtitles1.dfxp, picture.jpg, xmlfile.xml`.
3. The `testfolder` is dragged and dropped into `rootdir`.
4. During moving the `testfolder` directory, the assessment for packing has been performed.
5. Files `movie.mp4, picture.jpg, xmlfile.xml` has been already transfered, however `trailer.mp4` and `subtitles1.dfxp` are still in process of transfering.
6. The script begins to pack `movie.mp4, picture.jpg, xmlfile.xml` because requirements for packing are fulfilled. The `subtitles1.dfxp` and `trailer.mp4` are ommited, because they weren't counted into files that needs to be packed.

How can I prevent such situation? How can I make sure that there are no additional, optional files waiting to be fully transferred?

My idea was to check size of folder, before assessing the files for packing. I wanted to check current size of folder, wait one second and check size again. If size remains the same, it means that the transfer of files is complete. However another issue occured. To calculate folder size, sum of size of each file in folder is needed. It is not possible to directly check folder size. Also, during single file transfer, when checking size of file during transfer (e.g. I created a loop that check size of files in directory each second, and then dragged and dropped huge file), it already gives the final size.
All this brings me to conclusion, that it is not possible to check if folder is during transfer or if it already finished transferring.

Do you know any possible solution of making sure that all files are transfered?

```
while True:
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
        # Object FolderInfo contains objects 'FileInfo'
        folder = FolderInfo()
        folder.folderPath = dirpath
        obj = os.scandir(path=dirpath)
        for entry in obj: 
            if entry.is_file():
                # Object FileInfo contains information about path, filename, type (movie,trailer etc)
                file = FileInfo(entry.name)
                file.get_file_information(rootdir, dirpath)
                folder.append_file(file)
        # If at least 3 files were found, assessment for packing is performed.
        if len(folder.listOfFiles)>=3:
            # Verify checks if movie+image+xmlfile was found, if so it sets folder.packingFlag to True
            folder.verify()
        if folder.packingFlag == True:
            # Folder containing information of files paths that are going to be packed is passed to foldersReadyToPack list
            self.foldersReadyToPack.append(folder)
        obj.close()    
    if len(self.foldersReadyToPack) > 0:
        # After traversing through all directories in rootdir packingQueue is created, it contains folders of list foldersReadyToPack
        packingQueue = PackingQueue(self.foldersReadyToPack)
        # Here the packing is performed
        packingQueue.execute_packing()

time.sleep(int(self.scanTime))
```

Comment: Maybe you could show some code? You should be able to do this in a synchronous way.

Comment: I added code with explanations. It should give general overview what is going on in the script.